# What is the correct decision if there are 2 ways to solve a request of a document?

Tags: discussion, documentation

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/49507?draftId=42362

There was a simple request about the example being not much on to the point and asking for phrasing it in a way making more clear what is the point.

While I placed an edit making the topic much more specific, the linked proposal was thought to solve the problem by just entirely deleting everything.

After checking it was a ~15k user who proposed this change I felt insecure about my own edit beeing appropriate.

When I improved the example I wasn't that much into documents, that I knew, anyone could add new examples, and the example I just improved wasn't that much related at all. But my edit made it somewhat more clear. But I'm not that sure yet what would have been the better way?

The problem that we have no queue, or even the requirement of information needs to be related to a specific form of examples opens different approaches.

So my question here is, was my reason for rejecting the deleting proposal justified? And if not so, how to act in such a situation? Is it better to just edit content out? Or try to improve it as good as you can?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a quandary for all.

I've tried making *Improvement Requests* on numerous fundamentally bad examples in hopes they would get improved and to see how the system will work in that regard. Then someone comes along and somewhat improves it and turns it from a bad example into a mediocre example. They are using the system as intended but perhaps weren't equipped to go all the way from bad to good

Since I made an *Improvement Request* I get a  notification and can instantly click to go to the revision. Then I am stuck on deciding to approve an edit that only upgrades it to mediocre but still lacks details but does fix some of the issues that made it bad in the first place - per my recommendation, or reject the edit.

My preference then is I would rather see the whole example disappear but I don't have that option any more, or if I do the UI isn't clear enough for me to know how to suggest it get deleted

I think that when *Improvement Requests* are made there should be a way to approve an edit but with another request (or maintain original request) that the overall example could still use improvement.

Right now I am happy to approve deletions since the system isn't robust enough to handle these situations and it seems more difficult to turn garbage into gold than just get rid of the garbage completely

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes... wrote this off top of my head. "improvement requests". Will update...thx for clarification

Comment: You captured my sentiments so perfectly... that I'm scared. BRB, looking for my tinfoil hat!